# Verify Query Request Received

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a software system which queries data via OLEDB from an external SQL Server 2005. The query request is sent every 15 minutes. I want to verify that the SQL Server is receiving the query requests. How can I?

Answer (score 2):

Create a SQL Trace (server-side) and capture the [SQL:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) event.  You can filter on the `TextData` column to ensure you're only getting the query that you are looking to ensure is happening.

The easiest way to create a **server-side** trace would be to create it in SQL Server Profiler (which is innately a client-side trace), do a quick start and stop and script out the trace definition and run it in SSMS.  Please see this TechNet reference on [Server-Side Tracing and Collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx) for an exhaustive reference on the details how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I only want to know if the request is received. Could the request be received and not completed?

Comment: Sure.  Monitor the SQL:StmtStarting event then.